# redux state not updating (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I have 8 APIs when called save on the same redux state, and I am saving them like this in the reducer:

```
case types.EXPLORE_CHEF_BY_TYPE:
  return {
    ...state,
    [action.data.type + '_chefs']: action.data.data,
  };
```

for example it will be `trending_chefs`, `new_chefs` ...etc.

and in my component I have this:

```
function ExploreScreen({
  ...,
  ...exploreData
}) {

...     

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state.explore;
};
```

and to access the data I am doing this

```
const handleCategoryClick = useCallback((categoryName) => {
    const selected =
      selectedQuery.name.toLowerCase() + '_' + categoryName.toLowerCase();
    if (exploreData[selected]) {
      setSelectedCategory(categoryName);
      setData(exploreData[selected]);
    } else {
      selectedQuery[`dataFunc_${categoryName}`]();
      setSelectedCategory(categoryName);
    }
  }, []);
```

the problem is the data is not persisting, in the above function I am checking If I already called that API and if I did then I just fetch the data without calling the API. Am I doing something wrong here ?

I can't figure out what the problem is, since sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Also. I think the `exploreData` in the state is causing the problem.

Thank you for the Help.

Comment: The useCallback has missing dependencies so the function resulting has [stale closures](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-hooks-stale-closures/)

Comment: @HMR Thanks man, that solved my problem